# Render same selected number even in page refresh react js with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on pagination..

I don't want to make change in selected page in pagination on page refresh. For example:

I have selected page number 5. So, if i  refresh page it takes 1 by default. But what I want is when I select 5 even on page refresh my active page number should remain 5 instead of 1.

Below code is my paginatioon code:

```
const {data, currentPage} = this.state
let current = currentPage, rangeDots = [], l, arr = []
current = current < 2 ? current + 1 : current >= data.total_pages ? current - 1 : current
for (let i = 1; i <= data.total_pages; i++) {
    if (i == 1 || i == data.total_pages || i >= current - 1 && i <= current + 1) {
        l = l ? i - l !== 1 ? rangeDots.push(<a>...</a>) : null : l
        rangeDots.push(<a className={i==currentPage?'active':''} href='#' key={i} id={i} onClick={() => this.fetchData(i)}>{i}</a>)
        l = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

It's very simple to implement.

In your `fetchData` function, you can set the `currentPage` in `localStorage`.

```
localStorage.setItem('currentPage', page_number)  //here page_number might be your `i` passed to `fetchData` function
```

Get the `currentPage` from `localStorage`,

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     currentPage: localStorage.getItem('currentPage') ? localStorage.getItem('currentPage') : 1
  }
}
```

[Simple Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jp9m4h)

---

**Update**

You are calling `this.fetchData()` in constructor. `fetchData` is taking 1 argument which you are setting to `1` by default. So every time you refresh the page is it setting the value of `id` to `1`.

You need to make use of `componentDidMount` method for your API call, and pass `this.state.currentPage` to `fetchData` function.

I have corrected your code, see the demo.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jp9m4h)

Comment: Can it be done without localstorage?? I mean something with URL?

Comment: When you refresh the page your component's state is lost. Is there any specific reason to not use `localStorage`?

Comment: Any error? Check the demo link and make sure you are doing the same.

Comment: Actually value is getting store i mean when i console its storing the value but atlast when i refresh the page its active page sets to one...
Eg :-I have console This.state.currentpage inside render:-
output:-if i pressed  5 output :- 5
When i refresh the page it again sets to one

Comment: Are you storing `currentPage` from `localStorage` in constructor?

Comment: @Dodiyarutu, check the updated answer and demo link.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the page count in state of the component, when the page gets reloaded the state value will reset to the same intial value,
You can either pass the page count as a props or use a global statemanagement library like redux to solve this problem

Comment: heya..I am storing the current page  value in state..And want to store on refresh ..So can get prev value..Without local storage and  any library...@Ajay Ghosh